# what is the weight function in numerical integration?

Tags: integration

The weight function when integrating f(x) is p(x) and looks like

$\int{p(x)f(x)} dx$

If we're integrating f(x) why do we need to multiply some weighting before integrating?

Comment: The title mentions "numerical integration" but you make no reference to this topic in the body of the Question.  Please use the body of the Question to give a self-contained formulation of the problem you want help with.

Comment: Check out articles on orthogonal polynomials and quadratures.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use a weight function but it is convenient for applications and it's not restricted to numerical integration. See [Weight function at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weight_function).

Answer (score 1):

Certain functions are orthonormal only with respect to some weighting function in a specified interval in which case you would have something like

$$
\int_a^b f_i(x)f_j(x)w(x)\text d x=\delta_{ij}
$$

However, in the integral as you wrote it above, $p(x)$ would not necessarily be interpreted as a weighting function.